# Are github commit dates based on git or github repository?

Tags: git, date, github, commit

I pushed an old git repository to GitHub and, in contribution activity, the commit date of the repository said that I had committed to the repository before joining GitHub. Is this because the commit date bases itself on the git repository or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, does GitHub bases its commit dates on the git history

It is based on the git history. The date information is baked into each commit. The commit is an integral entity; when you push it to a remote repository, it remains the very same commit with the very same internal information, including the date.